# Constant light or flash

Tags: switches

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvEyMJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Hi all, thank you for you replies. I'm sorry that I gave you a poor problem description but here I try again. EM Fields got it right. Imagine 3 lamps: Lets say A,B and C. A and B are constantly on. C get pulsed signal from f.eks. flasher relay, when a switch is pressed. When the pulse is present on C lamp, it starts to flash ofcourse. Lamp B must start to flash on and off in step with the C lamp. When pulsed signal is switched off, the A and B go back to constant on. I hope this makes it easier to understand. The above timing diagram shows the two states.
Can it be done without using a microcontroller? It must be said that the space where this pcb isgoing to be places is very narrow and should rather be as small as possible.

---

1. The flasher is just a flasher lamp with LEDs as in a car. Flash signal comes from a so called flasher relay used in cars/trucks
2. All lamps are LEDs.
3. Whole system works on 24Vdc
4. On/off time isn't important but it is around 1sec between shifts.

I also came to a solution where I have LEDs flash in anti-phase but that is just not allowed according to requirement specs. 
I also came to a solution where LEDs flash in phase with each other but when flasher is turned off, the lamp that should stay on also turns off.

Comment: Ever heard of a truth table?

Comment: Please give step by step sequence of lamp operations with pulses.

Comment: Welcome to SE, AVO, but your question is very poor. "_I used two transistors and a mosfet for my attempt._" That tells us nothing. Do you not think that you should provide a schematic of your attempt. There's a button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: Part 1. Sounds to me like you have three lamps; lets call them A, B, and C. Then you have some sort of pulse generator which you can turn ON and OFF with, let's say, a toggle switch, and a switch to turn power to the rig ON and OFF.  So... to start it all off you have the POWER  and PULSE switches both OFF. Then, when you turn the POWER  switch ON, lamps A and B come on and stay on, and lamp C will stay off until you turn the PULSE switch ON. When you do that, lamp 3 will come on and start to, flash, and lamp B will flash in unison with it.

Comment: Part 2. After that, if you turn the PULSE  switch OFF, lamps A and B will be on and lamp C will be off until you turn the PULSE switch ON again, when the cycle will begin anew. Right?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to convey your full meaning if you post a flowchart that gives us all of the specific requirements for you circuit. As stated, there are too many variables in your question that you gave us no values for. Is this supposed to be a driver circuit for a vehicle's turn-indicator system (either in-dash indicators, or exterior signal lamps)?

Comment: Please provide circuit diagram, goto edit, then hit the circuit button and  draw the circuit

Comment: Too much hand waving.  It's not clear what exactly is supposed to happen when the pulsed line turns on, then off again.  A timing diagram showing the input signal and what each of the lamps is supposed to do would help.  This should be easy once there is a clear spec.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your question:

1. You don't explain what an f.eks flasher is.
2. You don't explain what kind of lamps they are (big theater lamps or a few LEDs).
3. You don't give the circuit voltage.
4. You don't give an on/off time.

The biggest problem is that you don't state how the circuit is to know when the last flash has occurred.

[image: ABC lamp timing]

*Figure 1. How does 'B' know that 'C' has stopped blinking and that 'B' should stay on?*

An easy solution, if you can tolerate it, is to have B and C flash in anti-phase.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpCTZk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 2. Lamps B and C in anti-phase.*

In this circuit A and B are normally on but every time C flashes B is turned off.

B could be switched with a transistor if, for example, it's a small load.

**Option 2** - if the flasher is turned on by changeover contact.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQbP5H.png)</sup>

*Figure 3. Simplest solution.*

Comment: I think "f.eks" is an attempt to abbreviate "for example".

Comment: Yes, sorry. f.eks = f.ex

Comment: Standard English is to use latin! "E.g." stands for exempli gratia, which means “for example.”

Comment: What turns on the flasher / Lamp C? Switch / relay contact? Is there a changeover contact available?

Comment: Added Option 2.